# What are the state space and the state transition function in AI?

Tags: terminology, definitions, search, state-spaces, transition-model

I'm studying for my AI final exam, and I'm stuck in the state space representation. I understand initial and goal states, but what I don't understand is the state space and state transition function. Can someone explain what are they with examples?

For example, one of the questions was this on my previous exam:

> Given $k$ knights on an infinite (in all directions) chessboard and `k` selected squares of the board. Our task to move the knights to these selected squares obeying the following simple rules:
>
> - All knights move parallel, following their movement rule (L-shape jump)
> - No knights can move to a square on which a knight stood anytime before
>
> Give the state space of the problem, the starting and goal states, and the state transition function!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Initial state

*How things are at first*.

In your particular example, it would be where your `k` knights are placed on the board initially. Your problem doesn't precisely state this, so you could either place them at the bottom or at random.

#### Goal state

The board with the `k` knights placed on the target squares.

#### State transition function

*A function that takes **actions** (bound presumably by rules) and returns a new state*.

In the `k` knight problem, the legal actions are moving parallel and in L shape movements, after which the knight will be in a new position and the board in a new state.

#### State space

*The set of **all** states reachable from the initial state by any sequence of actions*.

So, in the case of the `k` knight problem, your state space would start at the top with your *initial state* followed down by each individual movement of the `k` knights and the resulting new state. A graph where *lines are actions* and *nodes are new states* or a table are common representations of state space.

---

#### Reference

[Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), by S. Russell and P. Norvig.